# Как правильно настроить MS Visual Studio 2022 для поддержки модулей?

Tags: c++, модули, visual-studio-2022

Вот код, который не компилируется в MS Visual Studio 2022 (Версия 17.8.7):

```
import std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Standard library module demonstration\n";
}
```

Выводятся следующие ошибки:

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления    Подробности
Ошибка  C2230   не удалось найти модуль "std"   Modules1    main.cpp    1       
Ошибка  C2039   "cout": не является членом "std".   Modules1    main.cpp    4       
Ошибка  C2065   cout: необъявленный идентификатор   Modules1    main.cpp    4
```

Поддержка последних стандартов в настройках VS включена.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил. Нужно:

1. Обновиться до последней версии VS 2022 (v17.9.2).
2. В свойствах проекта поставить "*Да*" в параметре "*Проверка источников на наличие зависимостей модуля*", как на этой картинке:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]